# Git marks showing on page but are not in code

Tags: git

I have what looks like some git conflict marks on some of my pages but I cannot find it in my code. Any ideas on how to make this go away? Also, looked at the branches and there are no conflicts. I have 2 branches, dev and master, and it is on both of them.

[image: git marks]

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind, I found them. I am using Codeignter and the marks were spread through different models. Some of the marks were at the top of the page and some were at the bottom.

If anyone else has this issue, try searching only part of the marks and not the whole string. That is why I couldn't find it.

Comment: rolling on the floor laughing :D

Comment: don't forget to accept this answer if you find it useful ;-)